Why I can't access a disk partition in explorer even when I'm administrator?
Can someone please explain me why I can't access my disk partition and see used and free size of the disk in explorer as an administrator? Maybe I properly don't understand how NTFS system permissions work.
Here is my situation:

I have Windows Server 2022 with a data disk attached.
The data disk has NTFS partition with letter F:
I am a domain user added to the server as a member of the local 'Administrators' group.
I am connecting to the server using RDP under the domain user context.
When I open explorer.exe I see the disk partition but I can't see free and used size.
When I try to access the disk using explorer, I get error: "F:\ is not accessible. Access is denied".
When I try to access the disk using explorer running as administrator, I get error: "F:\ is not accessible. Access is denied"
The owner of the disk partition is 'SYSTEM'
The permissions of the disk partition contains the local group 'administrators'

When I add the local user group 'Users' with permissions: "Read & Execute, List folder contents, Read" on the disk partition everything is working. I can see free and used size, I can access the folders and files.
Why? Why I can't do these things without the group 'Users' when I am in a fact in the local Administrator group?

This sounds very much like an UAC thing. By default Administrators log in with a reduced security token which doesn't actually have the 'Administrators' membership in it – the expectation is that programs would "elevate" through UAC (the "Allow changes...?" prompt) when they need a full admin token.
Unfortunately, while most other file managers support running elevated, Explorer does not.

Use another file manager, e.g. Total Commander or one of its alternatives, which supports running "elevated" (with full Administrator access). TotalCmd also supports on-demand elevation (sudo style).

Create a custom group that you'd also be member of (e.g. "Storage Admins" or whatever) and grant that group access to the disk. Custom groups won't get filtered by UAC – only the built-in Administrators group does – so the limited token will still have access.

Turn off UAC. I've seen people argue that UAC is not very useful on servers and could be turned off without much risk, but you decide whether that's acceptable for you.



Thank you. When I installed total commander I have been able to explore the inside of the disk partition but at first I was asked for elevated permissions which on Windows Explorer was truly missing. I am still not able to see free and used size of the disk partition but that's because I run total commander without elevated permissions. When I run it as administrator I'm able to see it.

Then it might be a good idea to grant Users limited read permissions (i.e. non-inheritable aka "Applies to this folder only"), granting something like "Read Attributes" to the root of the volume, so that they could see used/free space. I usually grant everyone a non-inheritable "List folder contents" on the disk root, as well, since it doesn't reveal anything sensitive.
